# Some shortcuts in Windows start menu have wrong (always dark) background

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, colors, start-menu, dark-mode

In my Windows start menu, I have several Chrome shortcuts (Gmail, Outlook, Teams, OneDrive, To Do). They all have the same background, except To Do. How can I make To Do also have a light background?

[image]

**What I have tried/checked so far:**

1. The icon does have a transparent background in general, which is clear when searching for it:

[image]

2. The shortcuts all look the same in the Windows folder:

[image]

3. When Windows is in dark mode, the background is the same for all shortcuts. So I guess, the mode for this one item is always dark?

[image]

Comment: Most of the apps you listed are not connected to Chrome. Which is this To Do app?

Comment: You are wrong. They are ALL chrome shortcuts

Comment: You mean that they are shortcuts to web pages? How did you create them, and especially the To Do icon?

Comment: Yes, I create them equally simple via Chrome. Just select "More tools" in the menu and then "Create shortcut", that's it

Comment: From which website did you create the To Do shortcut?